# crontab not running jobs, yesterday it was ok

Tags: python, linux, cron, debian

```
which cron
/usr/sbin/cron
```

yesterday it was ok and jobs were running ok

today the jobs are not working and crontab -e shows some bad code
I edited as it was before

but cron not running this time

```
Mar 26 03:00:39 localhost cron[5988]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Mar 26 03:05:01 localhost CRON[6084]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 26 03:15:01 localhost CRON[6247]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 26 03:17:01 localhost CRON[6256]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 26 03:25:43 localhost cron[6391]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Mar 26 03:25:43 localhost cron[6391]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Mar 26 03:32:55 localhost cron[6493]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Mar 26 03:32:55 localhost cron[6493]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Mar 26 03:35:01 localhost CRON[6514]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 26 03:36:35 localhost cron[6527]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Mar 26 03:36:35 localhost cron[6527]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Mar 26 03:45:01 localhost CRON[6642]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

I tried a env.output file just not running any jobs

```
0 4 * * * /sbin/reboot
* * * * /tmp/env.output
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/mycode.py
```

just no any activity ...

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`? Unless you're using a Python script to write crontab entries, there is just a sysadmin problem, not a Python problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a, programming problem, but a system administration problem. (Whether it belongs on Server Fault, SuperUser, or a more specific site, I'm not sure; try them and read their help.)

Comment: @abarnet I wanna run my python script but the cron just not running any, how to tag the question ?

Comment: If the cron isn't running anything, it doesn't matter that one of the things it's not running is a Python script you wrote; the problem is that it's not running anything.

Comment: Why show us the output of `which cron`? `/usr/sbin/cron` is the cron daemon, and you never need to interact with it directly.

Comment: The second line of your crontab is wrong (and very dangerous). I assume that you did paste/copy from "wrong" internet (which has `env >`.

Answer (score -1):

Type:

```
pgrep cron
```

If you see no number, then cron is not running. sudo /etc/init.d/cron start can be used to start cron.

```
sudo service cron start
```

Comment: it;s all there but just not running jobs

Comment: Can you have a look here : https://serverfault.com/questions/680089/cron-job-occasionally-not-running and here https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it